# highcharts - chart names for multiple pie chart series in one chart

Tags: highcharts

I need to display multiple pie charts that are all related to the same data. As such I want them all to be part of the same chart and implement them as individual series.

This all works no problems until I tried to put labels/titles over each individual pie chart. It seems that I can only have a title over the entire group. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJcTZ/731/)

Is there any way to have the titles over each chart?

```
See above jsfiddle for example
```

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I'm stuck on the exact same issue and having trouble getting Labels for individual pie's

Comment: No, I ended up having to create separate charts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, and found this solution via highcharts support forum :
http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/3073133-pie-title

The Highcharts dude has written a plugin that you can see working on the following jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/tnSRA/

I have copy-pasted this plugin in a highcharts-plugins.js file that I included in my website, works like a charm!

Here's the plugin code :

```
/**
 * Pie title plugin
 * Last revision: 2012-12-21
 */
(function (Highcharts) {
    Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype, 'render', function (proceed) {

        var chart = this.chart,
            center = this.center || (this.yAxis && this.yAxis.center), 
            titleOption = this.options.title,
            box;

        proceed.call(this);

        if (center && titleOption) {
            box = {
                x: chart.plotLeft + center[0] - 0.5 * center[2],
                y: chart.plotTop + center[1] - 0.5 * center[2],
                width: center[2],
                height: center[2]
            };
            if (!this.title) {
                this.title = this.chart.renderer.label(titleOption.text)
                    .css(titleOption.style)
                    .add()
                    .align(titleOption, null, box);
            } else {
                this.title.align(titleOption, null, box);
            }
        }
    });

}(Highcharts));
```

And this is how you configure your title (put this in your series elements) :

```
title: {
            // align: 'left',
            // x: 0
            // style: { color: XXX, fontStyle: etc }
            text: '<b>Pie 1</b><br>Subtext',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: -40
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

To further improve on this, the code below correctly handles left, center, and right justification for the titles.  See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/9y4Lj4yr/ for an example.

```
    /**
* Pie title plugin
* Last revision: 2015-5-20
*/
(function (Highcharts) {
    Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype, 'render', function (proceed) {

        var chart = this.chart,
        center = this.center || (this.yAxis && this.yAxis.center),
        titleOption = this.options.title,
        box;

        proceed.call(this);

        if (center && titleOption) {
            box = {
                x: chart.plotLeft + center[0] - 0.5 * center[2],
                y: chart.plotTop + center[1] - 0.5 * center[2],
                width: center[2],
                height: center[2]
            };
            if (!this.title) {
                this.title = this.chart.renderer.label(titleOption.text)
                .css(titleOption.style)
                .add()
            }
            var labelBBox = this.title.getBBox();
            if (titleOption.align == "center")
                box.x -= labelBBox.width/2;
            else if (titleOption.align == "right")
                box.x -= labelBBox.width;
            this.title.align(titleOption, null, box);
        }
    });

} (Highcharts));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use renderer which allows to add text in any place.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text()

Comment: Thanks, is this the only option? I'd rather not position things absolutely

Comment: You can also have two charts is separate divs.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on Vincent's answer. This is how I used it for simple Text titles.

```
extendHighcharts = function(){
        Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype, 'render', function (proceed) {

            //Clear the title if added previously
            //if your chart data does not change, this reference storage for removal can be left out
            if(this.chart.subChartTitleElement){                            
                this.chart.subChartTitleElement[this.id].destroy();
            }   

            proceed.call(this);


            if (this.center && this.options.title) {


                //first, add the title, at center or anywhere, we need the container width to center it
                this.chart.subChartTitleElement[this.id] = this.chart.renderer.text(this.options.title.text,this.center[0],this.center[1]);
                this.chart.subChartTitleElement[this.id].css(this.options.title.style)
                this.chart.subChartTitleElement[this.id].add();

                //Center the title using the container(Bounding Box = BBox) width
                var xCenter = this.chart.plotLeft + this.center[0] - (this.chart.subChartTitleElement[this.id].getBBox().width/2),
                    yCenter = this.chart.plotTop + this.center[1] - 0.6 * this.center[2];

                this.chart.subChartTitleElement[this.id].attr(
                                 {
                                     x:xCenter,
                                     y:yCenter
                                 }
                );

                }
            }); 
     }
```

USAGE

```
                    this.chart.addSeries({
                        type: 'pie', 
                        name: 'pie_chart_1',
                        data: pieChartData,
                        center: ['80%','25%'],
                        size: '35%',
                        showInLegend: false,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },

                        //this part adds the relevant information
                        title: {
                            text:'Pie Chart Title',
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            y: -40
                        },
                        id:'a_unique_id_or_name'
                    });
```