# How to align two pie graphs (highcharts) next to each other

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I would like to have two pie charts to show up on my page, next to each other. They are both the same style but different data.
Is that possible and how?

Thank you

Comment: Include what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

You can have multiple series of pie chart data on the same chart

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'pie'
},
title: {
    text: 'Group Name'
},
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    center: ['20%'],
    name: 'foo'
}, {
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    center: ['80%'],
    name: 'bar'
}],
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }                
    }            
}
```

});

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4NtBw/

Comment: Is it possible to name each pie with their series name ?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640888/highcharts-chart-names-for-multiple-pie-chart-series-in-one-chart

Comment: Thanks ! This will be positioning the text under the pie exactly and would be out of place if the number of data series change.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to set the same [size](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size) for both charts. That would disable option to smart resize for pie with dataLabels and you will get two the same size charts both with enabled dataLabels.

Answer (score 0):

Search center at : http://docs.highcharts.com/#polar-chart
It might help

Comment: Sorry, it's at here : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.center